# SQL, select in tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

Hey I don't know how to do it....

Its a homework: List the code and the consumers who bought cars only 'Argentina' country.

> ```
> Table sell:
> ```

```
customer | resell  | veicle    |    date    |  value
---------+---------+-----------+------------+----------
 02      | 01      | 03        | 2010-02-05 | 17500.00
 04      | 02      | 01        | 2010-01-07 | 28000.00
 01      | 03      | 08        | 2010-02-15 | 28000.00
 02      | 03      | 02        | 2010-03-12 | 42000.00
 03      | 04      | 06        | 2010-02-06 | 11500.00
 03      | 02      | 05        | 2010-01-25 | 22100.00
 01      | 01      | 04        | 2010-01-21 | 15500.00
```

> Table customer:

```
 cod    |    name    | lastname
--------+------------+------------
 01     | Jose       | Alves
 02     | Paulo      | Cunha
 03     | Maria      | DPaula
 04     | Joana      | Silveria
```

> Table veicle:

```
 cod    |manufacturer|     model       | year |  country  |  price
--------+------------+-----------------+------+-----------+----------
 01     | 01         | Gol             | 2000 | Brasil    | 25000.00
 02     | 01         | Golf            | 2005 | Argentina | 39000.00
 03     | 04         | Ford Ka         | 1990 | Brasil    | 15000.00
 04     | 03         | Corsa Seda      | 1995 | Brasil    | 12500.00
 05     | 04         | Fiesta          | 2003 | Argentina | 20000.00
 06     | 03         | Corsa Seda      | 1995 | Argentina | 10000.00
 07     | 05         | Palio           | 2002 | Brasil    | 15000.00
 08     | 05         | Siena           | 2006 | Brasil    | 26000.00
```

I guess it to start:

```
SELECT customer.cod, customer.name 
FROM sell, customer 
WHERE (SELECT cod 
        FROM veicle 
        WHERE veicle.country = 'Argentina') = sell.veicle;
```

To select only the argentine cars...
Please guide-me to the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT c.*
FROM   customer c
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM   sell s
    JOIN   veicle v ON v.cod = s.veicle
    WHERE  s.customer = c.cod
    AND    v.country = 'Argentina'
    )
AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM ...
    );
```

I'll leave the rest for you, as this is homework. Fill in for `...` to exclude customers that have bought vehicles that are not from Argentina - very similar to the first `EXISTS` clause. If you have understood the first, you can complete the rest.

Comment: WOWWW I was minding an answer like that, but I didn't knew how to implement it, but you made me understand.

Comment: SELECT c.*
FROM   customer c
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM   sell s
    JOIN   veicle v ON v.cod = s.veicle
    WHERE  s.customer = c.cod
    AND    v.country = 'Argentina'
    )
AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM   sell s
    JOIN   veicle v ON v.cod = s.veicle
    WHERE  s.customer = c.cod
    AND    v.country != 'Argentina'
);

Comment: @mastergoo: Correct. You can also use the standard `<>` operator instead of `!=`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this 
`SELECT DISTINCT customer.cod, customer.name || customer.lastname FROM customer, veicle, sell WHERE customer.cod = sell.customer AND veicle.cod = sell.veicle AND veicle.country = 'Argentina'`

Comment: Oh, that is wrong yet, the return is only 1 row name: maria, cod = 03. Your anwer returned two rows. name: maria, name: paulo.

Comment: But Paulo also bought a 2005 Golf in Argentina.

Answer (score 0):

Look into table joins. That way instead of doing a subquery (what is in your where statement) you can instead join on the tables (kindof like your `From` clause but you should specify what it joins on) and then in your where you can just put veicle.country = 'Argentina'.

And FYI veicle is spelled wrong. It should be vehicle.

Comment: I do not understood.. Can you be more spcific ?

Comment: Seems you got your answer. Just join to the vehicle table and then in the 'where' put vehicle.country = "Argentina"

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
 SELECT c.cod, c.name,c.last_name,v.model
 FROM sell as s JOIN customer as c JOIN veicle as v ON s.veicle = v.cod and s.customer = c.cod
 WHERE v.country = 'Argentina'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH minima AS (
        SELECT DISTINCT s.customer
        , MIN(v.country) AS mi
        , MAX(v.country) AS ma
        FROM sell s
        JOIN veicle v ON s.resell = v.cod
        GROUP BY s.customer
        )
SELECT cu.* FROM customer cu
JOIN minima mm ON mm.customer = cu.cod
WHERE mm.mi = 'Argentina'
AND mm.ma = 'Argentina'
        ;
```